# When Cells match with certain columns in a table, do X

Tags: excel, vba

I have an "Import" sheet where I import data. On that sheet I have three cells that change value all the time, C3, C4 and C5.

When these cells match with the cells from another table on another sheet I want to manipulate the value of a different column within the same table.

It will look something like this:
[image: Information]

When Column A matches with Apples, and Column B matches with Oranges, and Column C matches with Peaches then I want to do something to the number on the same row of column D.

I wrote the following code but it is just returning all the numbers from column D.

```vb
Dim c1 As Range
Dim c2 As Range
Dim c3 As Range
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim r3 As Range
Dim a1 As Range
Dim a2 As Range
Dim a3 As Range

Set r1 = Sheets("Specificaties").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Set r2 = Sheets("Specificaties").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Set r3 = Sheets("Specificaties").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

Sleutel = Sheets("Specificaties").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set a1 = Sheets("Import").Range("C3")
Set a2 = Sheets("Import").Range("C4")
Set a3 = Sheets("Import").Range("C5")

For Each c1 In r1
    For Each c2 In r2
        For Each c3 In r3
            If c3.Value = a3.Value And _
              c2.Value = a2.Value And _
              c1.Value = a1.Value Then
                    
                For i = Sleutel To 3 Step -1
                    MsgBox Cells(i, 13).Value
                Next
                         
            Else
                MsgBox "Negative result"
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `range1`, `range2`, `range3`?  If you meant to refer to `r1`,`r2`,`r3` they would only be 1 cell ranges.

Comment: My bad, typo in the code. I'm sorry but I don't quite get what I should change to make it fit to my question.

Comment: Why not use autofilter?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @SJR that Autofilter would be a good choice, however this is an option.  This assumes that your column labels of A-D are in columns H-K based on your code or numerically 8-11 and that your data starts in row 4.  I only chose one of the columns for the length since there must be a value in all 3 columns in order to meet your described criteria.  Your 3 nested loops would not check each row in order.

```
Sub test()

    Dim r1 As Long
    Dim x As Long
    
    Dim a1 As Range
    Dim a2 As Range
    Dim a3 As Range
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Dim wks2 As Worksheet
    
    Set wks1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Specificates")
    Set wks2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    
    Set r1 = wks1.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set a1 = wks2.Range("C3")
    Set a2 = wks2.Range("C4")
    Set a3 = wks2.Range("C5")
    
    For x = 4 To r1
        If wks1.Cells(x, 8).Value = a1.Value And wks1.Cells(x, 9).Value = a2.Value And wks1.Cells(x, 10).Value = a3.Value Then
            MsgBox wks1.Cells(i, 11).Value
        Else
            MsgBox "Negative Result"
        End If
    Next x
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I couldn't quite get this to work. I get a 1004 error around the code ```MsgBox wks1.Cells(i, 11).Value ````

Comment: Change the `i` to `x`

Comment: I did and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help! I had to remove the "set" before "r1 = wks1.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row". But still working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using and is doing exactly what I'm looking for.

```
Sub Fruits()
Dim Criteria1 As Variant, Criteria2 As Variant, Criteria3 As Variant
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim wsImport As Worksheet: Set wsImport = Sheets("Import")
Dim wsSpec As Worksheet: Set wsSpec = Sheets("Specificaties")

Criteria1 = wsImport.Range("C3")
Criteria2 = wsImport.Range("C4")
Criteria3 = wsImport.Range("C5")

Set rng = wsSpec.Range("H3:H" & (wsSpec.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row))

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = Criteria1 And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Criteria2 And cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Criteria3 Then
        MsgBox cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    End If
Next cell


End Sub
```